# How to select specific values from a column in Presto sql?

Tags: presto

I would like to exclude the (Non-mall) from stall_type column so that I get only High End, Mid End, and Low End as values in my query output. Does anyone know if this can be done in presto sql?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by replacing the text you want to exclude by an empty string:

```
select replace("stall type", '(Non-mall)') from ...
```

more details on the use of the `replace` function can be found [on the presto docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html)